# Extensible Add Controller Dialog?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget

I can't find any articles on how to add custom scaffolding to the Add Controller dialog.  I know how to replace/change the existing templates, or add custom templates that can be run from the console, but I can't find how to add custom templates as additional options to the dialog.  Wondering also if the named parameters that I add to custom templates will show up in the dialog in some way.  from several blogs talking about the new extensible scaffolding:

"Add Controller Dialog supports extensible scaffolds via NuGet packages such as MvcScaffolding."
from: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

None of the articles as far as I can tell actually show how to add the custom scaffolds as an option to the Add Controller dialog.  They all are either changing the existing templates by overiding them, or are adding new ones which can only be run from the console.

**How do I add my custom templates to the drop down in the Add Controller Dialog?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx) from Phil Haack says:

> Add Controller Dialog supports extensible scaffolds via NuGet packages such as MvcScaffolding. This allows plugging in custom scaffolds into the dialog which would allow you to create scaffolds for other data access technologies such as NHibernate or even JET with ODBCDirect if you’re so inclined!

So I would start by downloading the [MvcScaffolding package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcScaffolding) and see if you can get any clues from there.

Comment: Thanks Danny. I had installed it separately from NuGet,even though it's part of the Tools Update.  The difference being NuGet installs files into only your current project, versus the Tools Update that installs templates in a more global level in the .NET Framework installation path.  Looking at what NuGet added, there is a hodgepodge of parametrized powershell scripts, templates, and config files that make it all work.  So it is not exactly straightforward, but I hope to put together a guide on how to do it when I have more time(sometime this century perhaps).